# HTTP Web request 500 Internal Server error?

Tags: vb.net

Am making a call to  a webservice but i get SOAPException error responds "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error" but when I use Wireshark or Fiddler I get Status error,status code and status description of the error not "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error".
How can I get these error information as well directly from vb2010

```
Sub readsoap()

    Dim webRequest As HttpWebRequest
    'Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim result As String
    Dim data As String = ""
    Dim url As String = ""
    Dim xdoc As New XmlDocument
    result = ""
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    Dim xml As String = ""

    xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:v1=""http://xmlns.bb.com/Request/V1"" xmlns:v3=""http://xmlns.bb.com/RequestHeader/V3"" xmlns:v2=""http://xmlns.bb.com/ParameterType/V2"">" _
    & "<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsse=""http://aaa.bb-open.org/wss/2004/01/aaa-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"">" _
      & "<wsse:Security>" _
         & "<wsse:UsernameToken>" _
            & "<wsse:Username>{8}</wsse:Username>" _
            & "<wsse:Password>{9}</wsse:Password>" _
         & "</wsse:UsernameToken>" _
      & "</wsse:Security>" _
   & "</soapenv:Header>" _
             & "<soapenv:Body>" _
              & "<v1:BRequest>" _
               & "<v3:RequestHeader>" _
                & "<v3:Information>" _
                 & "<v3:ID>{0}</v3:ID>" _
                 & "<!--Optional:-->" _
                 & "<v3:traID></v3:traID>" _
                 & "<v3:count>R</v3:coun>" _
                 & "<v3:corID>3465FGFRwsdss</v3:corID>" _
                & "</v3:Information>" _
               & "</v3:RequestHeader>" _
               & "<v1:requestBody>" _
                & "<v1:action>{10}</v1:action>" _
                & "<!--Optional:-->" _
                & "<v1:deb>{1}</v1:deb>" _
                & "<v1:cre>{2}</v1:cre>" _
                & "<v1:am>{3}</v1:am>" _
                & "<!--Optional:-->" _
                & "<v1:tId></v1:tId>" _
                & "<!--Optional:-->" _
                & "<v1:inId></v1:inId>" _
                & "<!--Optional:-->" _
                & "<v1:addiParam>" _
                 & "<v2:ParameterType>" _
                  & "<v2:parameterName>{4}</v2:parameterName>" _
                  & "<v2:parameterValue>{5}</v2:parameterValue>" _
                 & "</v2:ParameterType>" _
                 & "<v2:ParameterType>" _
                  & "<v2:parameterName>{6}</v2:parameterName>" _
                  & "<v2:parameterValue>{7}</v2:parameterValue>" _
                 & "</v2:ParameterType>" _
                & "</v1:addiParameters>" _
               & "</v1:requestBody>" _
              & "</v1:BRequest>" _
             & "</soapenv:Body>" _
            & "</soapenv:Envelope>"

    url = "http://123.456.78.5548:5545/abc/serv/custinfo"
    webRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    webRequest.Method = "POST"
    webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    webRequest.Proxy = CType(Nothing, IWebProxy)
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Dim postdata As String = String.Format(xml, "req", "123", "443", 100, "wedge", "0002", "con", "Prep", "", "", "")
    webRequest.ContentLength = postdata.Length
    webRequest.KeepAlive = True

    'Try
    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
    writer.Write(postdata)
    writer.Close()
    response = DirectCast(webRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        xdoc.Load(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) ' Fast
        txtResponse.Text = xdoc.InnerText
    End If

    'Catch ex As Exception
    'txtResponse.Text = ex.Message
    ' End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The actual error might be written in full in the event logs. Also, you might be interested in [How to: Embed Expressions in XML Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384752.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
     'REST OF CODE
 End If
```

Why don't you do:

```
Select Case response.StatusCode 

    Case HttpStatusCode.OK
    'HANDLE OK

    Case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
   'HANDLE SERVER ERROR BY ACCESSING THE ERROR MESSAGE RETURNED

    Case ... 'ANOTHER STATUS CODE

End Select
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the reply, but the exception is thrown on the below line:  response = DirectCast(webRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse), it doesnt go beyond that point